# Пример полной синтаксической парадигмы предложения

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Подскажите пример полной синтаксической парадигмы предложения (модель: подлежащее + простое глагольное  сказуемое + прямое дополнение). Не знаю как это делать.

Comment: ПОДСКАЗА́ТЬ. — 1. Тихо и незаметно сказать, чтобы помочь кому-нибудь ответить на вопрос.  2. перен. Навести на мысль, внушить какие-нибудь действия, слова.

Answer (score 1):

http://refdb.ru/look/2968147-pall.html

Самой полной является восьмичленная парадигма, куда входят следующие синтаксические формы предложения:

**3 формы синтаксического индикатива:**

1) синтаксическое настоящее – исходная, начальная форма. Он читает книгу.

2) синтаксическое прошедшее. Он читал книгу.

3) синтаксическое будущее. Он будет читать книгу.

**5 форм синтаксических ирреальных наклонений:**

1) сослагательное.  Потом он читал бы книгу.

2) условное. Если бы он  читал  книгу, то знал бы урок.

3) желательное. Хоть бы он читал книгу!

4) побудительное. Пусть он читает книгу.

5) долженствовательное. Тебе нужен реферат, а он читай книгу.